# Scripting User & Login Creation in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have a bunch of user accounts and server accounts which I need to create on SQL Azure (and then in 4 other environments for (dev,qa,uat & pre-production) and I'm running into some problems.

Problem 1. CREATE LOGIN must be done on master / CREATE USER must be done in the database. but since you can't switch databases with a `Use` statement, at the very least I'm going to need to do this in 2 batches.

Problem 2. You don't seem to be able to execute the CREATE LOGIN/CREATE USER code in either dynamic sql or as part of an `IF` block so I can't do an IF NOT EXISTS check around each create statement.

Am I snookered here, or are there any other easy/robust ways to script the creation of SQL Logins & DB Users with some basic existance checking in SQL Azure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Powershell for Azure to accomplish what you need.

Here is an example of how to create database:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/02/07/windows-azure-sql-database-management-with-powershell.aspx

Here is a powershell example of creating sql users:
http://sqldbawithabeard.com/2013/09/23/add-user-to-database-role-with-powershell/

Comment: any idea on how create Azure AD users w/ PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've resolved this, but I've just used this script in Azure SQL to create a login if it doesn't exist (running against `master`):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'Blah')
    CREATE LOGIN Blah WITH PASSWORD = 'BS#ah12!!@#' 
ELSE
    PRINT 'Already exist'
```

and this script to create the user if it doesn't exist (running against the actual database):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysusers WHERE name='Blah')
    CREATE USER Blah FOR LOGIN Blah WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
ELSE
    PRINT 'Already exists'
```

(As a side note I should be pulling the sid value from `sys.sql_logins` and using that to lookup `sys.sysusers`, but I'm using convention to work around that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36654590/1462905)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this does not actually answer the question posed above does it? This sysuser table exists in every database, and your script is only creating it in the context of the database it is running. (master).

Comment: The first script needs to run in a connection against master, and the second script runs against the database. I'll update the answer to make it more clear.