# SQL Azure: list all logins and users

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication, azure-sql-database

I'm using `V12 Azure SQL`.

To list all logins (`server level`) we can use this query on `master` database:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins;
```

To list all users (`database level`) we can use this query **on a specific database**:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysusers;
```

But how to get the correspondence between `logins` and `users`?

Where is the `system table` that stores this correspondence?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To find the login mapped for a user, look at the `sid` column from `sys.sysusers`.

This value corresponds to the `sid` column from `sys.sql_logins` in the master database.

Unfortunately, you cannot discover the login name for the `SID` while connected to the `user database`. You must connect separately to the `master` database once you have the `sid` and query `sys.sql_logins` to get the name.

Comment: There's a typo here: it should be sys.sql_logins, not sys.sys_logins (it's spelled correctly the first time, not the second).  I can't fix it since SO requires edits to change at least 6 characters.

Answer (score 4):

When connected to the master DB you can run this query to make a list of the Logins and the Users

```
select l.name as [login name],u.name as [user name] from sysusers u inner join sys.sql_logins l on u.sid=l.sid
```

I hope this may work

Comment: In Azure SQL V12 this will not tell you the the mapping of logins to users, if those users were created in a non-`master` db. Lonny's answer works but it's just a bit fiddly.