# Getting SQL logins available in a user database

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication

I have a lot of developers in several user databases and they need to know which logins are available.

As I see in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36654590/9563642), I can't do it directly so I tried the next query but Azure don't support it.

```
SELECT * 
INTO [myDb00037].dbo.copyOfSql_logins
FROM sys.sql_logins
```

I would like to know if there is any way to do this (not manually as possible)

Comment: Yes, indeed I know, I see, I reference it in my post saying that I want a possible alternative of this

Comment: What do you mean by an "alternative"? What's wrong with `sys.sql_logins`?

Comment: What is worng with `sys.sql_logins` is that I can't use it in user database, as I say in my post.

Comment: Yes, the post you link to states you need to connect to `master`. The problem seems to stem from the fact you are trying to store this data in a separate database; you don't need to. The data is always available in `sys.sql_logins` and will always be up to date. Storing it elsewhere would create stale data.

Comment: Note that if you want the users on a database (a `LOGIN` and `USER` are different) then the linked post also explains that; they are located in `sys.sysusers` and that would be able to be queried from your user database.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but I need to make it available for user databases

Comment: Like the post says then, you can't. `sys.sql_logins` isn't available for access from a user database; that is a design feature of Azure. The best thing I can suggest is exporting the list of the logins in `sys.sql_logins`, and then exporting the results from `sys.sysusers` on your databases. Then match the `SID` outside of Azure (which is what the accepted answer effectively suggests).